# How to properly apply a customized function to a dictionary of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert specific columns inside a dictionary of df's (wheter they have or not `%`), to floats.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'dataframe_1':pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['John', 'Ashley'], 'col2': ['+10', '-1']}), 'dataframe_2':pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['Italy', 'Brazil', 'Japan'], 'col4': ['Milan', 'Rio do Jaineiro', 'Tokio'], 'percentage':['95%', '0%', '80%']})}

######## converting all columns to strings ###########

for key in data:
     data[key]=data[key].astype("string")

##### defining function to convert to percentage ######

def convert_to_percentage(x):
    
    if '%' in x:
        x=x.str.strip('%')
        x=x.astype(float)/100
        
    
    else:
        pass
    
    return x
```

However when the function is applied:

```
for key in data:
     data[key].apply(lambda x: convert_to_percentage(x))
```

It returns a df without any change:

```
data['dataframe_2']

#   col3    col4             percentage
#0  Italy   Milan               95%
#1  Brazil  Rio do Jaineiro     0%
#2  Japan   Tokio               80%
```

Expected Output

```
data['dataframe_2']

#   col3    col4             percentage
#0  Italy   Milan               0.95
#1  Brazil  Rio do Jaineiro     0.00
#2  Japan   Tokio               0.8
```

What am I missing? Is there any other simpler way to convert to float percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the return value from the call to apply to anything...

```
for key in data:
     data[key].apply(lambda x: convert_to_percentage(x))  # <<== 

# should be:
for key in data:
     data[key] = data[key].apply(lambda x: convert_to_percentage(x))
```

... and your function doesn't check correctly:

```
def convert_to_percentage(x):
    if x.str.contains("%", regex= False).any(): # this does what you want
        x = x.str.strip('%')
        x = x.astype(float) / 100
    else:
        pass
    return x

## Try this:
df = data["dataframe_2"]

"%" in df["percentage"]   # doesn't work
>> False

df["percentage"].str.contains("%", regex= False).any() ## Does work
>> True
```

Although, the last part does actually check something, it just doesn't check the values, it checks the index.

```
# Try this:
df["percentage"]
>>>
0    95%
1     0%
2    80%
Name: percentage, dtype: string

1 in df["percentage"]
>> True

df["percentage"].index = list("abc")
df["percentage"]
>>
a    95%
b     0%
c    80%
Name: percentage, dtype: string

"a" in df["percentage"]
>> True

df
>>
     col3             col4 percentage
0   Italy            Milan        95%
1  Brazil  Rio do Jaineiro         0%
2   Japan            Tokio        80%

"percentage" in df
>> True
```

This is because Series and DataFrames are similar to dictionaries. Just like the `in` keyword operating on a dictionary, it will check the keys/index rather than the values:

```
d = dict(a= 1, b= 2)
"a" in d
>> True
1 in d
>> False
```